# Where to store a user's preferences in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like the users of my Rails app to be able to choose how many records of their `projects` get displayed per page.

So I have this helper function (which in turn is based on the `will_paginate` gem):

```
def paginate(object, items = 10)
  object.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => items) 
end
```

I am using it like this in a lot of places throughout my app:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    projects = current_user.projects
    @projects = paginate(projects, current_user.preferences.items_per_page)
  end

end
```

Now while this works I don't like that the database gets hit every time a user's `preferences` are required. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not just write `current_user.preferences.items_per_page` into `session[]` the first time you access it, and subsequently read the session value? (But are you certain Rails isn't managing to cache that value anyway)?

Comment: Please don't succumb to pre-optimization.  Your current_user is cached by the app server and the fetch costs you nothing